# HttpTestScript Recorder in java

Tags: java, jmeter

Does anyone know how to add `HTTPTestscriptRecorder` to jmeter using java code? pls help me.
I have successfully added the workbench and Recording controller in Threadgroup
but unable to add `HTTPTestscriptRecorder`

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import junit.framework.TestSuite;

import org.apache.jmeter.control.LoopController;
import org.apache.jmeter.control.gui.LogicControllerGui;
import org.apache.jmeter.control.gui.LoopControlPanel;
import org.apache.jmeter.control.gui.TestPlanGui;
import org.apache.jmeter.control.gui.WorkBenchGui;
import org.apache.jmeter.gui.tree.JMeterTreeNode;
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.RecordingController;
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.gui.HttpTestSampleGui;
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.gui.RecordController;
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.control.gui.JavaTestSamplerGui;
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JavaSampler;
import org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService;
import org.apache.jmeter.testelement.TestElement;
import org.apache.jmeter.testelement.TestPlan;
import org.apache.jmeter.testelement.WorkBench;
import org.apache.jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup;
import org.apache.jmeter.threads.gui.ThreadGroupGui;
import org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils;
import org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree;

public class Jmeter {
    public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
        // Initialize the configuration variables
        String jmeterHome = "/home/ksahu/apache-jmeter-2.13";
        JMeterUtils.setJMeterHome(jmeterHome);
        JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties(JMeterUtils.getJMeterBinDir()
                + "/jmeter.properties");
        JMeterUtils.initLogging();
        JMeterUtils.initLocale();

        // TestPlan
        TestPlan testPlan = new TestPlan();
        testPlan.setName("Test Plan");
        testPlan.setEnabled(true);
        testPlan.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, TestPlan.class.getName());
        testPlan.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, TestPlanGui.class.getName());

//        LogicControllerGui lc= new LogicControllerGui();


        RecordingController rc=new RecordingController();
        rc.setName("Recording Controller");
        rc.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, TestElement.class.getName());
        rc.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, LogicControllerGui.class.getName());

        // ThreadGroup controller
        LoopController loopController = new LoopController();
        loopController.setEnabled(true);
        loopController.setLoops(5);
        loopController.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS,
                LoopController.class.getName());
        loopController.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS,
                LoopControlPanel.class.getName());

        // ThreadGroup
        ThreadGroup threadGroup = new ThreadGroup();
        threadGroup.setName("Thread Group");
        threadGroup.setEnabled(true);
        threadGroup.setSamplerController(loopController);
        threadGroup.setNumThreads(5);
        threadGroup.setRampUp(10);
        threadGroup.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS,
                ThreadGroup.class.getName());
        threadGroup.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS,
                ThreadGroupGui.class.getName());

        // JavaSampler
        JavaSampler javaSampler = new JavaSampler();
        javaSampler.setClassname("my.example.sampler");
        javaSampler.setEnabled(true);
        javaSampler.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS,
                JavaSampler.class.getName());
        javaSampler.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS,
                JavaTestSamplerGui.class.getName());

        // Create TestPlan hash tree
        HashTree testPlanHashTree = new HashTree();
        testPlanHashTree.add(testPlan);

        // Add ThreadGroup to TestPlan hash tree
        HashTree threadGroupHashTree = new HashTree();
        threadGroupHashTree = testPlanHashTree.add(testPlan, threadGroup);


        // Add Java Sampler to ThreadGroup hash tree
        HashTree javaSamplerHashTree = new HashTree();
        javaSamplerHashTree = threadGroupHashTree.add(rc);




        RecordController rd=new RecordController();
        rd.setName("Record Controller");
        HttpTestSampleGui http=new HttpTestSampleGui();






        WorkBench wb=new WorkBench();
        wb.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, WorkBench.class.getName());
        wb.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, WorkBenchGui.class.getName());
        wb.setName("WorkBench");
        testPlanHashTree.add(wb);


        javaSamplerHashTree = wb.add(rd);
//        wb.addTestElement();



//        http.putClientProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS,
//                JavaSampler.class.getName());
//        http.putClientProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS,
//                JavaTestSamplerGui.class.getName());

//        testPlanHashTree.add(http);






        // Save to jmx file
        SaveService.saveTree(testPlanHashTree, new FileOutputStream(
                "/home/ksahu/MyScreenshots/k.jmx"));
        System.out.println("completed");
    }
}
```

Comment: what did you try to do and what was the problem?

Comment: i tried above code but cannot add httpsTestScriptRecorder to the workbench

Comment: @KumaraSwamyThota are you able to find the solution ?